# Nodemailer: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

Tags: nodejs, nodemailer

Hice una aplicacion que tiene un formulario de contacto y quiero que cuando alguien envia el formulario me llegue un correo, configure nodemailer pero recibo el mensaje

> Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

Por ahora estoy probando la funcion en Postman:

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();
const emailRouter = router
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

emailRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let { email, name, message } = req.body

        const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 587,
            auth: {
                user: 'micorreo@gmail.com',
                password: 'mipassword'
            },
            secure: false,
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        })
        await transport.sendMail({
            from: email,
            to: 'micorreo@gmail.com',
            subject: name,
            html: `<p>${message}</p>`
        })
        res.status(200).json('Ok')
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send(error.message)
    }
})

module.exports = emailRouter
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en el nombre de la propiedad "password" de auth.
En vez de ser password debería ser pass.

```
auth: {
    user: 'micorreo@gmail.com',
    pass: 'mipassword'
},
```

Comment: Sí, gracias, ya lo pude resolver. Eso lo había hecho pero igualmente no funcionaba. Por alguna razón en local no funciona pero en producción si.